# Referencing QWidget from different class

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I'm sorry if this question is duplicate but i am really struggling with finding any answer.

Please take in mind that i am novice in c++ programmming.

My problem is this. I have an GUI made in **QtCreator**. There are **two** **listeners** binding `keyReleaseEvent`, one on main class (`SuperFalcon`) , one on **QTextEdit** ( which is separate and modified class ). I have **QFrame** which i would like to **toggle** hide/show on **"Ctrl + f"** key event. Since that **QFrame** (object name is `findWidget`) widget belongs to **SuperFalcon->ui**, there's no problem, everything works fine, problem starts when i try to make **"Ctrl + f"** in **QTextEdit** because it's separate event listener. Basically i tried this.

main class name is "SuperFalcon" so:

in `superfalcon.h` i've made an public static pointer like this:

```
public:

    static QFrame *fWidget;
```

then in `superfalcon.cpp`, i firstly execute

`ui->findWidget->hide();` and then

`fWidget = ui->findWidget`;  hoping to get pointer on widget.

Next in my QTextEdit class in `keyReleaseEvent` function i've tried to get that pointer like `SuperFalcon::fWidget->show()` but i get undefined reference on it.

So , to make things simpler, i don't know how , if possible, to get reference of QFrame widget which is part of one class (SuperFalcon), from another class (QTextEdit class) in order to execute some commands on QFrame.

If it's not clear enough i can provide some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a definition of any static member variable.
This definition has to be in a source file because of the one definition rule.

Simply add the line:

```
QFrame* SuperFalcon::fWidget;
```

to "superfalcon.cpp".

Comment: i am getting this error 
 qualified-id in declaration before '=' token

Comment: You have to put the definition outside of any function in the global space of the source file. This should fix it.

Comment: I don't know what kind of sorcery is this, but it works, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize your static variable, in superfalcon.cpp:

```
QFrame* SuperFalcon::fWigdet = nullptr;
```

Comment: i am getting this error 
qualified-id in declaration before '=' token

Comment: Thanks for the help, i have managed to make it with Unterfliege's suggestion of putting it in global space